# How can I bind UJS to a series of elements that all have the same class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I don't know how to iterate through anything in the DOM except for elements.

So I know how to do:

```
$("div").each(function (i) {
  if (this.style.color != "blue") {
    this.style.color = "blue";
  } else {
    this.style.color = "";
  }
});
```

But I don't know how to iterate through a bunch of objects that have the same class. I can't find how to do so anywhere. Can anyone help?

I mean take a look at this sample:

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("div").each(function (i) {
    if (this.style.color != "blue") {
      this.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
      this.style.color = "";
    }
  });
});</script>
```

Seriously? OK, then why is there an "i" in the second function declaration but not in the first? What the heck is that "i"? Why does it need to be there if it's not referenced anywhere? And this is from the jQuery site itself. Sheesh, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i` is the index of the iteration like the `i` you would use in a `for` loop structure. Its an optional parameter to each because its not necessarily needed because unless the index matters to your internal logic its irrelevant.

Note that `jQuery.each()` invoked statically is different than when invoked on a jQuery collection. In the former the `i` comes first and the second argument is the actual value and it can be used to iterate over any array like object.

```
$([1,2,3,4,5], function(i,value){
  alert(i + '=' + value);
});
```

Whereas when invoked on a collection you are expected to use `this` to refer to the value because its a dom element.

```
$('a[href]').each(function(i){
   alert(i + '=' + $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Now as far as your question regarding the css:

> I want to fire that sample code in the mouseover event.

```
$('div').mouseover(function(event){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.css('color') != 'blue'){
     $this.css('color', 'blue');
   }
});
```

Most of the jquery function automatically iterate through a collection applying oyur callback to every element of the collection. So when doing something with an event you dont need to use `each`, its implied by the event binding function youre invoking. Aditionally with event binding functions you dont get the index as an arg to your callback instead you get the `event` object.

Most of the time though, you dont actually need access to the event since `this` is bound to the element that triggered the event which is generally what your after unless youre doing something really complex.

Answer (score 1):

When you are having trouble thinking how to select something in jQuery, go [read the documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). For your needs:

```
$('.someclass').each(function(){
  var me = $(this);
  me.css('color', me.css('color')!='blue' ? 'blue' : '' );
});
```

**Edit**: Based on new information (desire to bind to a mouseover event):

```
$('.someclass').mouseover(function(){
  var me = $(this);
  me.css('color', me.css('color')!='blue' ? 'blue' : '' );
});
```

Comment: Thank P, I didn't know enough even to know they were called "selectors" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have the class "test", then your jQuery would look like:

```
    $(".test").each(function () {
      if (this.style.color != "blue") {
        this.style.color = "blue";
      } else {
        this.style.color = "";
      }
    });
```

Update: mouseover

```
    $(".test").mouseover(function () {
      if ($(this).css('color') != "blue") {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
      } else {
        $(this).css('color', '');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Event for what? You just want to iterate through the elements w/ the same CSS class, right?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's documentation of the .each method explains what the parameters passed into the function are.

jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )
collection: The object or array to iterate over.
callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement): The function that will be executed on every object.